# how do I make arrays to be of the same length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a pickled file that contain a hash with key -> list
like this

```
h = { 'two': [1,2], 'three': [3,4,5]}
```

I want to convert the arrays into an array of array, making the arrays of the same length (just filling up with zeros for the shorter arrays)

So the example above I would like to have a result like this

```
>>> np.asarray([[1,2,0],[3,4,5]])
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

(I don't care about the keys in the hash, and I also don't care about the order of the arrays).

The first step would be to find the longest array, which I think this code will do for me

```
m = max(map(len, h.values()))
```

But how do I create the arrays after that?
I thought numpy.copyto() would be possible;
copying the original array into a new array filled with zeros and the new length, but it demands arrays of the same shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you start with a dictionary, it's very unlikely this can benefit from numpy vectorization; So solution would be bare loops, and you can `pad` zeros either in `numpy` way with `np.pad`:

```
np.array([np.pad(v, (0, m - len(v)), 'constant') for v in h.values()])
#array([[1, 2, 0],
#       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Or vanilla list way:

```
np.array([v + [0] * (m - len(v)) for v in h.values()])
#array([[1, 2, 0],
#       [3, 4, 5]])
```